# Nested Models when API Endpoint differs in field names from model with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I receive the following json:

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "created_at": "2019-10-22T14:18:09-04:00",
    "person": {
        "id": 7234,
        "name": "John Smith"
    },
    "ticket": {
        "id": 5432,
        "person_id": 7234,
        "name": "How to fix this function?"
    }
}
```

And I want to serialize and then save to a db with the following tables: Event, Person, and Ticket where Ticket is described as follows:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Ticket(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    ticket = models.ForeignKey('Ticket')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

What ought the Ticket Serializer to look like? Currently, I have what doesn't work:

```py
class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Ticket

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            data['person'] = data['person_id']
        except KeyError:
            pass

       return super().to_internal_value(data)

class EventSerializer(UniqueFieldsMixin, NestedCreateMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person = PersonSerializer()
    ticket = TicketSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Event
```

The error I get reads:

```
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'ticket': {'person': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid pk "7234" - object does not exist.', code='does_not_exist')]}}
```

Comment: Hi, @Mikr. Could you please provide all of the models?

Comment: @EliakinCosta I've provided the Person and Event models. The problem occurs at the serializer.is_valid() stage, which suggests that I need a way to tell the TicketSerializer not to check whether the Person exists until it reaches the save() method (and then to ensure that the Person serializer saves first). I just can't tell if there is (or what it would be) a DRF way of doing it.